# Create a virtual folder from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is it possible to create a virtual folder in IIS from an ASP.NET site?

Sample:
I have a website `http://www.example.com/myApp` and from within that application, I want to create `http://www.example.com/userfiles123` (and point it to a actual folder somewhere else on the machine)

If not, any other suggestions on how to schedule a "create virtual directory" command from an asp.net page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DirectoryServices` can be used to connect to IIS and create Virtual Directories.

I found this bit of script on [Codersource.net](http://www.codersource.net/csharp_iis_metabase.html) used to create a Virtual Directory:

```
public void CreateNewVirtualDirectory(int ServerId, string VirtualDirName, string Path, bool AccessScript){
      DirectoryEntry Parent = new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/" + ServerId.ToString() + "/Root");
      DirectoryEntry NewVirtualDir;
      NewVirtualDir = Parent.Children.Add(VirtualDirName, "IIsWebVirtualDir");
      NewVirtualDir.Properties["Path"][0] = Path;
      NewVirtualDir.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = AccessScript;
      NewVirtualDir.CommitChanges();
}
```

Also found an example in ASP.NET just like you wanted. [See this blog post](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/06/20/createdeleteview-virtual-directory-or-website-in-iis-using-c/) for more information and downloadable code.

Answer (score 0):

suppose this is ur path

- **C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite1**

then do this

go to iis and select the websites----then in that expand the default website ---- then rightclick the ourwebsite name and -----select new from that and give virtual directory and tehn there give the permisssions in the sharing and then-- give the alias name to that ------then apply and ok then expand the website name and in the wizard select our default.aspx file and explore tyaht one then it will be hosted

Comment: My question is how do I do this from code, not how to do it in IIS manager.